# setting state within nested response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I am building a react app and I am setting the `state` with `api` of `nested response` of `nested state` But the state is not setting the way I want.

response that is receiving from `api`

```
[
    {
        "id": 70,
        "title": "feefifef",
        "images": [
            {
                "id": 28,
                "text": "First Image"
                "blog_id": 70,
            },
            {
                "id": 28,
                "text": "First Image",
                "blog_id": 70,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        blogs = [
           {
            id: 0,
            title: "",
            images: [
                 {
                    id:0, 
                    text:""
                 }
               ]
            }
          ]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    let data;

    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blogs/').then((res) => {
        data = res.data;
        this.setState({
            blogs: data.map((blog) => {
                return Object.assign({}, blog, {
                id: blog.id,
                title: blog.title,
                images: blog.images,
                }
                })
            })
        })
    }

    render() {

         const blogs = this.state.blogs.map((blog) => (
           <BlogList
              id={blog.id}
              title={blog.title}
              images={blog.images}
           />
        ))
    }

    return (
         <div>{blogs}</div>
    )

}


class BlogList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }


    return (
         <div>
            Title: {this.props.title}

            Images: {this.props.images}
         </div>
    )
}
```

**What is the problem ?**

Images are not showing after `Title`. I am trying to show all images in `BlogList` class of every blog.

I have also tried using (in `BlogList class`)

```
this.props.images.map((img) => {
    return (
        <div>
        Title: {this.props.title}

        Images: {img.text}
        </div>
    )
}
```

But it showed me

> this.props.images.map is not a function.

then I think the problem is with `setting state` of images (I may be wrong).

When I tried to print `this.props.images` then it is showing

```
0: {id: 28, text: '1111', blog_id: 71}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

I am new in react, Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance

Comment: I think you could print in the callback function of this.setState whether blogs is what you expect, and then in the lifecycle of the BlogList component that listens for updates, print whether this.props.images is the correct data structure

Comment: When I print `console.log(this.props.images` then it is showing **0: {id: 1, text: '1111', blog_id: 71}
length: 1**

Comment: Your BlogList is a class component, but when you render the result, you write a return directly, is this OK? I haven't written a class component in a long time, so I'm not sure if this is the problem

Comment: Yeah! But how can I `create a map function` in `this.props.images` ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-violet-dprmxw?file=/src/BlogList.js I created a codesandbox inside is like you a direct return compiler directly reported an error

Comment: {
                "id": 28,
                "text": "First Image"
                "blog_id": 70,
            },   You seem to have a problem with this data, I don't know if it's the original data, or if you made a mistake when copying it, it seems to be missing a comma

Comment: You can take a look at this codesandbox I tweaked your code a bit and it renders the results properly

Comment: Thanks @AmelloAster, It worked, You really helped me, I learnt a lot from you. You made my day

Comment: Glad to help you solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.props.images is an array and hence you can't use {this.props.images} directly. Other wise you will get an error like this "Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead"

You have to use something like this

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Title: {this.props.title} <br/>
        Images:
        {this.props.images?.map((image, i) => (
          <div key={image.id}>
            {image.id}<br/>
            {image.text}<br/>
            {image.blog_id} <br/>
           </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```